# Javascript format int value to specific style

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

Hello I am looking for a solution to compare 2 values in cypress.
expected value == 34 000,00 , my value 34000
Does anybody know `Intl.NumberFormat` or any other to set my value to correct style?

Comment: There are internationalisations libraries that can handle this correctly. I've used one called `i18Next` and it seemed pretty good. It could do all manner of regional number formatting, including the Indian number groupings.

Comment: Do you mean expected `value == "34 000,00"`? Are you looking for a function to format the value? If so, mentions of cypress may be omitted, I guess. Please clarify your question and also show some attempts of yours

Answer (score 0):

### Using [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat):

```
var number = 34000;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL', { style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(number));

// Output: "34 000,00"
```

Comment: @MichalParciak you're welcome! Feel free to accept the answer if it is the case.